# How do I turn on vim syntax highlighting via modeline?

Tags: vim, modeline

In my .vimrc file I have

```
syntax off
```

Suppose I want to turn on syntax highlighting on a case-by-case basis via vim's modeline? I've tried many combinations, like:

```
# vim: syntax on:
```

but I still can't get it to work. What do I need to do in the modeline?

Comment: 1) For which file extension are you trying to include the syntax?
2) Does anything happen after typing the `syntax on` (possibly errors appear)

Comment: @Jossnix Typing :syntax on turns on syntax highlighting.

Comment: I don't understand the end goal ...
Should syntax be turned on or off?

Comment: @Jossnix The default should be that the syntax is off. But I want to turn it on on a per file basis.

Comment: Enable every time or prescribe in the vimrc?

Answer (score 2):

According to `:help syntax`, using `syntax enable` or `syntax on` loads syntax files at runtime. But there's also apparently `syntax manual` which turns it on based on the syntax type you specify. Looking at the source vimscript, it says:

> It installs the Syntax autocommands, but not the FileType autocommands.

You can therefore use `syntax=` to set the type, and that works in a modeline to either set a specific type or set `none` which effectively turns it off.

```
# vimrc
syntax manual
```

```
# In your files
# Turn it on for this yaml file
# vim: syntax=yaml:

# Or this PHP file
# vim: syntax=php:
```

If you want to be explicit about disabling it in a file:

```
# In your files
# No syntax highlighting for this file (default if omitted)
# vim: syntax=none:
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim is a multi-buffer/window/tab editor. Changing global state (syntax, colorscheme, loading plugin etc.) per current file is a wrong habit. Luckily, modeline does not allow this.

What you can do in the modeline is to set `:h local-options`. Accidentally, there's an option also named `:h 'syntax'`. And it has the same syntax as any other option.

```
# vim: syntax=OFF
```

You don't need to set `:syntax manual` for this to work, as modeline has preference over filetype detection. However, if FileType event is fired manually (e.g. `:setf xyz`) while `:syntax on` then buffer's syntax could be redefined to match new filetype. Not a problem though.